# What Is A Simple Way Sync 2 Codebases Different Directory Structures

Tags: merge, windows-xp, directory-structure

So I work at a company and the codebase isn't where I want it in terms of organization and  so I adopted the Maven Convention. I have run into a problem, I now have 2 directory structures...

Existing Codebase

```
project
  subproject
    src
      com
    JUnitSrc
      com
```

My Codebase

```
Project
  src
    main
      java
        com
    test
      java
        com    
Project
....
```

If I update say the existing I want to be able to merge changes into my codebase and vice versa. What are some ways I can do this? Also the current development environment is Windows XP so Linux commands are great if I can get them working with Bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cobian backup http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm
Free and fast syncing.

Good luck